# MS Access - Query Need Assistance

Tags: sql, ms-access

I stumbled across this website and instantly fell in love. Let me be completely honest, I have little to NO knowledge of Access.. I told my manager this and he still insists that I "can figure it out" which is highly doubted. So here I am asking for help.. On to the question:

Where are the SQL code gurus? haha

I have 2 tables, "Found" & "Missing", both showing inventory adjustments for our building within the company. (Amazon)

I believe I have the process figured out but have no idea how it looks within Access..

Step 1: Group by ASIN (basically the numerical version of a barcode)

Step 2: Determine the +/- for the grouped ASINs in both lists

Step 3: Use TOP function to find the largest negative adjustments

There is a total of 3000+ records in both spreadsheets, but hopefully if I can figure out the process then the input/output wouldn't matter.

I thought maybe I needed a unique identifier? Bin(location) + ASIN(barcode) + Quantity

As you can see.. I have been thinking, organizing, and praying someone can help!

Here is a dummy example of the "Found" spreadsheet, the "Missing" spreadsheet is the exact same format with the only difference being a "M" instead of a "F" under "Reason Code"

Hopefully this is enough information, I know its a cluster.... thanks guys!

```
Date         FC      Application Name   IOG ID  IOG Name    Container Id    GL Product Group    ASIN        Processed By    Reason Code   Quantity     Item Cost    
1/5/2014    RIC1    FCICQACountService  1234    Doll Inc.   P-1-A101xxx     Toy               B000000001       unknown1         F          -1           12.34   
1/5/2014    RIC1    FCICQACountService  1334    Amazon      P-1-A101xxx     Drugstore         B000000002       unknown2         F          -1          10.36    
1/5/2014    RIC1    FCICQACountService  1432    Amazon      P-1-A102xxx      Office Product   B000000003       unknown3         F          -13          50.50
1/5/2014    RIC1    FCICQACountService  1442    Amazon      P-1-A102xxx     Office Product    B000000004       unknown4         F          -2          223.62   
1/5/2014    RIC1    FCICQACountService  1337    Hope Inc.   P-1-A102xxx     Office Product    B000000005       unknown5         F          -1           100.99
```

Comment: What's your expected result from this?

Comment: Before this occurrence, I had never opened Access. I was hoping for guidance.. from individuals knowledgeable on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it that by "spreadsheet", you actually mean "table". Might be a good idea to find a good primer on SQL and relational databases in general.

You've got a pretty good start, though. You've identified what you want. Note that in SQL, this is what you usually do; you think more about the result you want than you do the process of getting it. Each of your points suggests a keyword or function that will go into your query:

1) "Group by ASIN (basically the numerical version of a barcode)": You probably want to use the `GROUP BY` keyword.

2) "Determine the +/- for the grouped ASINs in both lists": Sounds like you want to `SUM` up a column here.

3) "Use TOP function to find the largest negative adjustments": Obviously, you already know you want `TOP`. The piece you're missing, though, is that the "largest negative" part suggests you want to use `ORDER BY`, and you want the smallest (largest magnitude negative) first. That will make sure that the right row is on top when it takes the top one.

So putting all that together, the only thing you need to figure out is the syntax. Your end query probably looks something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ASIN, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity FROM Found GROUP BY ASIN ORDER BY SUM(Quantity);
```

This will calculate the sum of `Quantity` for each group of rows that has the same `ASIN`, and the result will be a set of rows that contain the `ASIN` and the total `Quantity` for that `ASIN`. Then it sorts the rows using the total quantity, with the smallest (most negative) row on top. The `TOP` then cuts off all the other rows. You could optionally leave out the `TOP 1` if you want to see all the rows.

By the way, this `SUM` function is a little special. It's what we call an *aggregate* function. That's because it does something with a bunch of values across many rows. Not all functions are like that in SQL, but this one is.

If this isn't exactly what you're looking for, I hope it's enough to get you off the ground. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked for both tables, now I'm stuck again.. I need to find the difference between the query results.. basically what doesn't end up net zero needs to show in the new query.. Wow, Access has been trying to kill me.

Comment: @Vinnie I think that warrants a new question.